# JQuery UI Tabs loads slow on iOS7

Tags: jquery, ipad, ios7, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a contact us tab that uses JQuery transition to animate out from the side when clicked.  The form is actually 4 different forms that are using JQuery UI tabs module to hide/show the different forms. It is working fine on desktop browsers and even iOS6 on iPad and iPhone, but when I load the contact form on iOS7 on iPhone or iPad there seems to be a slight delay when loading the tabbed content causing the tab to remain invisible for several seconds, sometimes until you scroll the window. The problem goes away when I remove the call to the JQuery tab function. You can view the test site here:
http://testing.meadowsandohly.com/wordpress/

How can I get the tabs to work on iPad? Is this a known issue with JQuery UI Tabs?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was because the contact tab was set to position:fixed. Changing it to position:absolute fixed it. The roll out animation was also controlled by the Transit jquery plugin, which could have had something to do with it.